# Matrix Norms Inequality Proof

Tags: normed-spaces

How do I prove this inequality / equivalence about matrix p-norms?
It appears on the wikipedia and mathworld.wolfram pages on matrix norms without proof.

$\|A\|^2_2 \leq \|A\|_1 \|A\|_\infty$

Maybe a proof of this would look a lot like a proof of Holder's inequality?

Comment: Just write the expanded sum of $tr (A^T A)=\sum_{i,j} |A_{ij}|^2$ and use the simplest upper bound you have

Comment: I think you might be mistaking the matrix 2-norm for something else. In fact what you're describing is called the Frobenius Norm, which is different. The matrix 2-norm is NOT the sum of the square entries. It's defined as 
$\|A\|_2 = \max_x \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$, where on the right hand side we're using the usual vector 2-norm (sum of square entries). It can be proven that $\|A\|_2 = \sigma_{max}(A)$, the largest singular value of A.

Comment: I don't know if this is still actual but $\|A\|_2^2=\rho(A^*A)\leq\|A^*A\|_1\leq\|A^*\|_1\|A\|_1=\|A\|_{\infty}\|A\|_1$ :-)

Comment: Yes, I think that works, @AlgebraicPavel; for anyone wondering, the first inequality comes from the fact that $\rho(A) \leq \|A\|$ for any matrix norm.